# Error parsing OmniFaces 2.1 Taglib when deploying to WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.6

Tags: jsf, websphere, omnifaces

I am seeing an IO exception during project startup on WebSphere Liberty for the Omnifaces tag library.  I have googled extensively and cannot find this happening for anyone.  This error DOES NOT happen in my local running the same version of WAS.  Here is the stack trace, does anyone have any knowledge of this?

```
[10/9/15 13:34:23:882 PDT] 000000fb TagLibraryCon E   Error Loading Library: wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/NC-SBWSNode01Cell/eNC3ExtWeb_EAR_V1.8.ear/eNC3ExtWeb_WAR.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-2.1.jar!/META-INF/omnifaces-ui.taglib.xml
                             java.io.IOException: Error parsing [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/NC-SBWSNode01Cell/eNC3ExtWeb_EAR_V1.8.ear/eNC3ExtWeb_WAR.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-2.1.jar!/META-INF/omnifaces-ui.taglib.xml]: 
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:637)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:668)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:93)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compileViewMetadata(Compiler.java:125)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:311)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:376)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1984)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.access$000(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:132)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage$FaceletViewMetadata.createMetadataView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2093)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:161)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:672)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at gov.nc.dor.app.ext.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:59)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

EDIT:

If it is not 8.5.5.x then why does this display on server boot?

```
    ************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere [IBMJAVA7 7.0.9.10 cf071533.01]Platform 8.5.5.7 [ND 8.5.5.7 cf071533.01] running with process name NC-SBWSNode01Cell\NC-SBWSNode01\server1 and process id 4740
Host Operating System is Windows Server 2012 R2, version 6.3
Java version = 1.7.0, Java Runtime Version = pwa6470sr9fp10-20150708_01 (SR9 FP10), Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
user.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java_1.7_64/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/web/help;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java_1.7_64/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;.;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb70-20150520.00
************* End Display Current Environment *************
```

Comment: That stack trace looks like it comes from WAS classic, not from WAS Liberty. WAS Liberty doesn't support the AIO TCP channel in the stack and threading works differently so the bottom of the stack isn't right. Are you sure the app is failing in WAS Liberty?

Comment: Alasdair - you were absolutely correct, I was confused thinking that there was only ONE WebSphere version 8.5.5.6 which had to be liberty.  Did not understand or realize that WAS 8.5.5.6 and WAS Liberty 8.5.5.6 could be different.

Comment: The version applies to the product which is WAS. There are two server profiles (for want of a better word) that are part of the product, WAS Classic and WAS Liberty. If you switch to WAS Liberty and configure jsf-2.2 as a feature it seems likely it will work.

Comment: I am literally giddy from learning this information, though my nightmare is far from over.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. You can get liberty from wasdev.net/downloads

Comment: Alasdair, WAS Liberty is an outstanding product, btw.  How is it, though, that WAS Classic gave me so many deployment issues, but WAS Liberty worked out of the box?  Granted I installed the javaee-7.0 bundles with WLP - and I was not involved in the initial install of WAS Classic.  Is it possible that our IT guy did not add the available bundles during the initial install and thats why I had my issues?  Im going to try this out tomorrow, but at any rate I wanted to let you know I like WLP way better.  So much easier to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.io.IOException: Error parsing [.../omnifaces-ui.taglib.xml]: 
>   at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:637)

This parsing error is recognizable as [MyFaces issue 3537](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3537) which is fixed in MyFaces 2.0.14 and 2.1.8. This suggests that you're actually deploying to a WebSphere version with a MyFaces version that old and not a JSF 2.2 compatible one as required by OmniFaces 2.x. The stack trace also confirms that it's not MyFaces 2.2.

Either upgrade the server to a JSF 2.2 compatible one, or downgrade OmniFaces to 1.x.

Comment: Now my biggest concern is that I'm not running liberty.  That may explain some of the other issues I've been having.  Please take a look at an excerpt from my SystemOut log.

Comment: I was a bit too quick with saying that it's not Liberty 8.5.5.x. It might be one with a customized JSF impl/version. At least, `TagLibraryConfig#loadImplicit()` method (2nd line of trace) doesn't exist in MyFaces 2.2. It existed in MyFaces 2.0/2.1 only. Line numbers of `org.apache.myfaces.*` classes suggest MyFaces 2.0. I haven't worked with WebSphere for long, but I know you could configure JSF impl/version at appserver level. Perhaps this is what happened here? I've at least clarified the answer.

Comment: I am not sure.  I am new to WAS as well, and I thought that if my server version was 8.5.5.6 or higher it meant that i had the liberty profile WAS.  Now im wondering if that is not the case.  I know I developed everything locally using java 1.7 and I've upgraded this server's java to 1.7 so im not sure whats going wrong with my install.  I did no custom JSF implementations.

Comment: Log file suggests it's WebSphere Application Server, not WebSphere Liberty. WAS 8.5.5.x ships with MyFaces 2.0.5.

Comment: Unreal so there is a vanilla WAS with the same version number as WAS Liberty?  That is unbelieveably confusing.  So:

WAS 8.5.5.6 is NOT the same as WAS Liberty 8.5.5.6??

Comment: It's indeed unfortunate that they didn't change the versioning for Liberty.